# Visio margin setting with vba

Tags: excel, vba, visio

I want to use VBA to open a visio file and change all margins of shape then save the file, please help me! I use the code below but speeds very slow(file size 12Mb (80 pages) takes 30 minutes). Please help me!

```
Dim visDoc As Visio.Document
Dim visio_doc
Dim Save_visio_doc
Dim ObjVisio As Object
Dim pag As Visio.Page
Dim pagShape As Visio.shape
Set ObjVisio = CreateObject("Visio.application")
vSet visDoc = ObjVisio.Documents.Open("C\test.vsdx")
For Each pag In visDoc.Pages
    For Each pagShape In pag.Shapes
        pagShape.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowText, visTxtBlkLeftMargin).FormulaU = "2 mm"
        pagShape.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowText, visTxtBlkRightMargin).FormulaU = "2 mm"
        pagShape.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowText, visTxtBlkTopMargin).FormulaU = "2 mm"
        pagShape.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowText, visTxtBlkBottomMargin).FormulaU = "2 mm"
    Next
Next
Visdoc.Save
Visdoc.Close
```

If anyone can assist, it would be greatly appreciated. Regards

Comment: That is the correct way to do the job. I don't think you'll get it done any faster. How long does it take?

Comment: file size 12Mb (80 pages) takes 30 minutes

Comment: Are the shapes based on a master? In which case you might want to edit the master and have those changes automatically propagate

Answer (score 0):

Try change these margins for style which names **Normal**! Usually most part of shapes in document use this style...

```
Sub FixNormalStyle()
Dim vsoStyle1 As Visio.Style
Set vsoStyle1 = ActiveDocument.Styles.ItemU("Normal")
vsoStyle1.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowText, visTxtBlkLeftMargin).FormulaU = "0 pt"
vsoStyle1.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowText, visTxtBlkRightMargin).FormulaU = "0 pt"
End Sub
```